# How to check whether a (key, value) pair is in a array which includes lots of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have a array:

```
array = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6}]
```

Is there any good way what I can check whether key value pair ('a', 5) is in this array or not.

Comment: define "good way". pythonic? fast run time? elegant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [61]: any(d.get('a', None) == 5 for d in array)
Out[61]: True
```

Wrapping this into a function:

```
In [64]: check = lambda arr, (k, v): any(d.get(k, None) == v for d in arr)

In [65]: check(array, ('a', 5))
Out[65]: True

In [66]: check(array, ('z', 5))
Out[66]: False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [88]: array = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6}]

In [89]: if any(d['a'] == 5 for d in array):
   ....:     print True
   ....:
True
```

or you can write something like

```
In [96]: array = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6}]

In [97]: def check_pair(k, v, l):
   ....:     for elem in l:
   ....:         if elem.has_key(k) and elem[k] == v:
   ....:             return True
   ....:     return False
   ....:

In [98]: check_pair('a', 5, array)
Out[98]: True

In [99]: check_pair('a', 11, array)
Out[99]: False
```

Comment: That'll raise an exception if you try a key that isn't in the dictionaries. This may or may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: @NPE: this solution is for this specific case only, as user has very specific requirement of checking  ('a', 5)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating through all the elements in the dictionary, you can just index by key and check if the value equals the queried value, but nevertheless, you have to iterate through the array elements

```
>>> array = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6}]
>>> foo = lambda k, v:any(e.get(k, None) == v for e in array)
>>> foo('a',5)
True
>>> foo('a',6)
False
>>> foo('b',5)
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

a more expansive method, alows to extract the exact dict in which your desired pair lies.

```
>>> array = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6}]
>>> for d in array:
    if ('a', 5) in d.items():
        #your code here
```

you can extract the first dict that meats your pair.

```
desired_dict = [d for d in array if ('a', 5) in d.items()][0]
```

or a list of them:

```
desired_dicts = [d for d in array if ('a', 5) in d.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     python 3.2

     [(m,n) for i in array for m,n in i.items() if (m,n)==('a',5)]
```